# Number of kills is always the same for every player. (Bukkit)

Tags: java, bukkit

As I was coding, I tested my plugin and this seemed to happen: 
basically, when a player kills another player, his kill count goes up by one. However, when a player has for instance 5 kills, so will all the other players. Here is my code:

```
    public class KillDeathCounter extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {
        new PlayerListener(this);
        getLogger().info("Players will not be able to kit spam.");

        this.getConfig().addDefault("playerkills", 0);
        this.getConfig().addDefault("playerdeaths", 0);
        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);

        saveConfig();
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Kill Death Counter has been disabled.");
        saveConfig();
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label,
            String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("digipvp")) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA
                    + "Our PVP plugin was developed by Pierre Lichtlé, the owner, also known as Master Digi."
                    + " If you would like to contact him for a plugin, send him an email at developer.petlamb@gmail.com."
                    + " Thanks for playing on our server!");

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
}


    package me.katsunicalis.plugin;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Statistic;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;

public class PlayerListener implements Listener {

    KillDeathCounter kdc;



    public PlayerListener(KillDeathCounter plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
        kdc = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void playerKillsPlayer(EntityDeathEvent e) {


        Entity deade = e.getEntity();

        Entity killer = e.getEntity().getKiller();

        if (killer instanceof Player && deade instanceof Player){



            int kills = kdc.getConfig().getInt("playerkills");
            int deaths = kdc.getConfig().getInt("playerdeaths");
            kdc.getConfig().set("playerkills", kills += 1);
            kdc.getConfig().set("playerdeaths", deaths += 1);


            killer.sendMessage("You now have " + kills + " kills!");
            deade.sendMessage("You now have " + deaths + " deaths!");

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks very much guys! :)

Comment: You are increasing the number of kills/deaths on a global scope (saved in your plugin's config). You need to save the individually for every player (scoreboard, NBT data etc.).

Comment: Yes, but do you know how to do this? I can't access the Player interface so I'm not sure :/

Comment: Digging through Bukkit's javadoc it seems like you need to keep track of the scores yourself; saving them to a file and reading them on launch again for example. I recommend using the UUID of a player as their identifier.

Comment: Is there no way of just adding a separate integer value for each player?

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you : https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-scoreboards-teams-with-the-bukkit-api.139655/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're increasing the same variable for every time a player kills another player. To fix this, you should use a different variable for each player, for example `"kills.playerUUIDHere"` and `"deaths.playerUUIDHere"`.

To get a player's [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), you can use [`player.getUniqueId()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#getUniqueId()), then to get the `String` representation of the [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), you could use [`uuid.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()). So, you could do something like this to change a player's kills:

```
String uuid = player.getUniqueId().toString();

int kills = kdc.getConfig().getInt("playerkills." + uuid);
kdc.getConfig().set("playerkills." + uuid, kills += 1);
```

The same logic can be used for deaths, so, you could use something like this for your `playerKillsPlayer()` method:

```
@EventHandler
public void playerKillsPlayer(EntityDeathEvent e) {
    Entity dead = e.getEntity();
    Entity killer = e.getEntity().getKiller();

    if(killer instanceof Player && dead instanceof Player){
        String killerUUID = ((Player) killer).getUniqueId().toString();
        String deadUUID = ((Player) dead).getUniqueId().toString();

        int kills = kdc.getConfig().getInt("playerkills." + killerUUID);
        int deaths = kdc.getConfig().getInt("playerdeaths." + deadUUID);
        kdc.getConfig().set("playerkills." + killerUUID + , kills += 1);
        kdc.getConfig().set("playerdeaths." + deadUUID, deaths += 1);


        killer.sendMessage("You now have " + kills + " kills!");
        dead.sendMessage("You now have " + deaths + " deaths!");
    }
}
```